# Batch file not appending and if statements not working correctly

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im at witts end trying to figure out what's wrong with my batch file

I can't seem to get some of the statements to work, and the final echo statement isn't appending tot he document. Can anyone chime in?

I want the first num to terminate if the user inputs 66

I also want the second num to jump to ZeroError if the user inputs the zero

I can't figure out why it isn't appending at the end to display the average or creating the one.txt file

---

```
@echo off



setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


type NUL > results.txt

:MAIN
echo My Name is ****** > results.txt
echo The Current date is  %date% >> results.txt
echo The Current time is %time% >> results.txt
echo My name is ****, the current date is %date%  and the current time is %time%

:FirstNum



SET /P FirstNumber=Enter the First Number and press Enter :
if %FirstNumber% == "66" goto LOOP


:SecondNum

SET /P LastNumber=Enter the Second Number and press Enter: 
if %LastNumber% == "0" goto ZeroError
if %LastNumber% == "66" goto LOOP
goto CALC


:ZeroError
SET /P zError =You CAN NOT divide by Zero, enter a correct number and press Enter:
if %LastNumber% == "66" goto LOOP
if %LastNumber% == "0" goto ZeroError
goto CALC

:CALC



set /A calculation = %FirstNumber% / %LastNumber%
echo %FirstNumber% divided by %LastNumber% equals %calculation%
echo %FirstNumber% divided by %LastNumber% equals %calculation% >> results.txt




pause


:LOOP

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,10) DO(

SET /A  MOD= %%A %% 6
SET /A MODPlus= !MOD! + 2
SET /A TOTAL  += !MODPlus!
SET /A AVERAGE = !TOTAL!/10

)

echo The mean of the values is %AVERAGE% >> results.txt

mkdir pgm4
cd pgm4
type NUL > one.txt
echo REM ***** >> one.txt
echo echo ****** >> one.txt
ECHO. >> one.txt
```

---

- In my FirstNum label the program just keeps going despite me entering 66 in the prompt
- Similar issue in SecondNum
- the echo after the :LOOP doesn't append the average value to the text file.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what Im doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put quotes on _both_ sides of the equals sign. `if "%FirstNumber%"=="66" goto LOOP`. I'm not posting this as answer because I'm too busy looking for the question that this is a duplicate of.

Comment: And the value of AVERAGE is incorrect because you need to use `!AVERAGE!` instead of `%AVERAGE%`.

Comment: @SomethingDark thank you, I still can't get the echo to append the average though. Not sure why

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem. I'm getting the line that says that the mean of the values is 7.

Comment: @SomethingDark well thanks for the corrections anyway. I tried it on my virtual machine and got the same error. Very odd.

Comment: Is the variable not printing anything or are you not getting the line at all? If you're not getting the line at all, are you getting the other lines?

Comment: @SomethingDark I get the line with my name, the one with the date and the one with the time and the division line. It just happens to be that last echo line not working, as well as the one.txt segment but that's another story

Comment: @SomethingDark : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173673 is the same calculation (from a few hours ago...) and the problem with the "no output appended" would be that OP is using point-click-and-giggle instead of using the command prompt. The `do(` in the `for /L` loop is a syntax error - it must be `do (`

Comment: @SomethingDark Thank you so much!

Comment: @SaintLaurent - Before posting to SO, you should remove `@ECHO OFF` in order for cmd to tell you (as much as it will) about what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need to be spoon fed sigh,

- to compare for equality both sides need to be equal, if the user enters `"66"` and only then the command `if %FirstNumber% == "66" goto LOOP` could evaluate true
- excessive white space doesn't make your code easier to read.
- `set /a` calculations can be combined in one line, and don't need `%` or `!` for vars (except for vars).

---

```
echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:MAIN
( echo My Name is ****** 
  echo The Current date is  %date%
  echo The Current time is %time%
) >result.txt 
echo My name is ****, the current date is %date%  and the current time is %time%

:FirstNum
SET /P FirstNumber=Enter the First Number and press Enter :
if "%FirstNumber%"=="66" goto LOOP

:SecondNum
SET /P LastNumber=Enter the Second Number and press Enter: 
if "%LastNumber%"=="0" goto ZeroError
if "%LastNumber%"=="66" goto LOOP
goto CALC

:ZeroError
SET /P zError =You CAN NOT divide by Zero, enter a correct number and press Enter:
if "%LastNumber%"=="66" goto LOOP
if "%LastNumber%"=="0" goto ZeroError
goto CALC

:CALC
set /A calculation=FirstNumber/LastNumber
echo %FirstNumber% divided by %LastNumber% equals %calculation%
echo %FirstNumber% divided by %LastNumber% equals %calculation% >> results.txt
pause

:LOOP
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,10) DO (
  SET /A  "MOD= %%A %% 6, MODPlus=MOD + 2, TOTAL+=MODPlus, AVERAGE=TOTAL/10"
)
echo The mean of the values is %AVERAGE% >> results.txt
mkdir pgm4
cd pgm4

( echo REM *****
  echo echo ******
  echo.
) > one.txt
```